# smtp server authentication

Tags: php

I am new with php.my website is hosted on plesk server.mail function does not work properly.when submitted the form A warning occured :smtp server authentication required in mail().How can i remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify your php.ini file.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php

or you could try using something like the pear mail package,

http://pear.php.net/package/Mail